# Document-based app's 'New Document' dock menu item won't open new document

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocument, nsmenu, nsdocumentcontroller

My document-based app has a dock menu with a 'New Document' item. The dock menu is made in Interface Builder, its item's action is connected to 'First Responder's `-newDocument:`

The document controller is a subclass of `NSDocumentController` called `DocumentController`.

In the app delegate this code is used to prevent the opening of an untitled document upon launch (instead the document controller's open panel is shown) :

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender {

    [(DocumentController *)[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] openDocument:self];
    return NO;

}
```

If I now launch my app, it'll show the open panel instead of an untitled document. If I then click on the dock menu's 'New Document' item, no new document opens. If I click on the standard file menu option 'New Document' in the template main menu, a new document does open.

I can't think of a reason as to why this is so, can you? How do I get the dock menu to open a new document?

---

EDIT : [Here is a sample project which has no NSDocumentController subclass but still has the same problem.](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jt2x8oe16g4ddb6/AAA7hr7ApJiTlKYxoKX5ZpV_a?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

Menu item calls newDocument method on the document controller. If you click on the dock you trigger NSApplication stuff and it's delegate. E.g. if you have a existing app window than you will not get called there. No window will trigger applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile

In your document controller override like this:

```
- (id)openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:(BOOL)displayDocument error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError {
  [self openDocument:nil]
}
```

And instead of responding to appdelegate(should bla bla) do this if you want after launch to display openPanel. If you want to trigger it when user clicks on the icon then do the second method

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [(DocumentController *)[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] openDocument:nil];
}

- (BOOL)applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender {
    return YES;
}
```

> The action of the File menu's New item in a document-based application. The default implementation of this method invokes
>   -openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:error: and, if nil is returned, presents the error in an application-modal panel.
>
> - (IBAction)newDocument:(id)sender;

Comment: That opens the open panel every time the user wants to create a new document. What I want to achieve is to display an open panel upon launch, then the user can click 'New Document' in my dock or file menu to create an untitled document (while the open panel disappears). Everything works, except the dock menu - for some reason it never calls `-newDocument:`

Comment: Your sample project  works. I click dock icon and hit new document->  it opens new document window. When the open panel is displayed it won't open new window because you are in different runloop (runloop of openpanel).

Comment: Thanks for the help, when the open panel is displayed the 'File > New Document' item works but the equivalent icon I put in the dock doesn't, is this because of a different runloop?

Comment: play with [NSApp stopModal] after open document + call new document from menu.

Comment: If you want your code to work correctly then don't call openDocument in  "applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile. Don't call it in app delegate at all. Subclass nsdocumentcontroller if you want to get written behaviour.

Comment: I presume I can just open a modeless `NSOpenPanel` in the `NSDocumentController` subclass?

Comment: NSDocumentController => - (instancetype)init NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER; Here is the correct place to do it +do it withCompletionHandler so init can return and your app can continue launching.